# Update Mongo fields from file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a DB called myDatabase and a collection called test.

I have a file called Name.csv with the contents below:

David

Ronaldo

Smith

Messi

Phlip

Jeremy

Sahid

What I like to do is:

1) Read data from file Name.csv

2) My collection test has field called fisrt_name which contain same value now. So I want to update the field named first_name with the names in the above file randomly.

What I have tried is:

```
use myDatabse

var file = cat('/home/milan/Desktop/Names.csv');  // read the file

var name = file.split('\n'); // create an array

for (var i = 0, l = name.length; i < l; i++){

   db.test.find().forEach(function(doc){db.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{"first_name":name[i]}});});

}
```

Note: I didn't get any result or error from the above script

I want result something like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467cbb"), "first_name" : "David" } //first name from file

{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467ccc"), "first_name" : "Ronaldo" } // Second name from file

{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467cdd"), "first_name" : "Smith" } // third name from file
```

Comment: You have not defined `words`. At least not in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the Mistake,It is edited now

Comment: Again. `name` would probably be just one long string. You would need to split on the comma `,` or something. You know there is an upsert option in [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mode). There's the link. It would probably be cleaner to just use that rather than try and roll this in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

We can update mongo database from the file in this way:

```
use myDatabase

var file = cat('/sample data/contact/Name');  // read the file

var words = file.split('\n'); // create an array of words

var totalContacts = db.test.count();

for (var i = 0, j = 0; i< totalContacts ; i++,j++){

  if(j < words.length){

  db.crm.test.find().skip(i).limit(1).forEach(function(doc)

{
db.crm.test.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{'first_name':words[j]}});});

 }
 else

 {

 j = 0;

 i =  i -1;

} 

} 

This gives exactly this result:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467cbb"), "first_name" : "David" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467ccc"), "first_name" : "Ronaldo" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("141491ee909f1a779b467cdd"), "first_name" : "Smith" }
```

If there are more ObjectId than the data in file then it again starts iterating from the begining.

Note: Saving file in .csv creates problem So I Saved file from Notepad and named it Name.

Answer (score 0):

Without using script, from mongo console, one can try this way

mongoimport -d  -c  --type csv --file  --headerline

In this command replace the <..> values with your required data

Instead of , it will be test

Instead of  it will be /home/milan/Desktop/Names.csv

mydb  -> Please give the database name